# What does "that’s how much." mean in context?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What does "that’s how much." mean in context?

> ...Anyway, that was the night she got pregnant with Jeremy and it was
>   the same night she decided she would leave you, because you couldn’t
>   stop looking at her, and thanking her, and she hated that. For sure
>   she hated it. She lives in Tulsa, that’s how much.”

Flood Show
by Charles Baxter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is making a sort of joke about how terrible it is to live in Tulsa.

How much did she hate you looking at her and thanking her?

She hated it so much that she moved to *Tulsa*, of all places.

The speaker's idea is that Tulsa is such a terrible place that she must've *really* hated the looking and thanking if she would move *there*.